# Multi threading issue

Tags: java

I need to initialize an `Array` of `n` `Threads`. Each `Thread` represents a number which randomly initialized in the `Thread's Object` creation.

The program should run `m` iterations. On each iteration, the `Threads` number needs to be updated. If both left and right neighbors in the `Array` are bigger than this `Thread` then the `Thread's` value will get +1 in the next iteration. If both neighbors values are lower then the `Thread's` value then the `Thread's` value will get -1. Otherwise, the `Thread's` value will not change.

The code starts from a code line in a GUI class. The line is:

`Controller cont = new Controller(n,m)`

The code enters updated method in class Controller just once and then all the `Threads` are going to sleep without implementing updated method.

Why is that?

This is my code:

```
public class Threads extends Thread
{
    private int num;
    private Controller cont;
    private int toUpdate;
    private int index;

    public Threads(Controller c, int i)
    {
        num = (int)(Math.random() * 100 + 1);  // random number between 1-100
        cont = c;
        index = i;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        for(int j = 1; j <= cont.getIterations(); j++)
        {
            toUpdate = cont.checkValue(this, this.getIndex());
            cont.finished();
            cont.threadWait();
            num += toUpdate;
            cont.updated();
            cont.threadWait();
        }
    }

    public int getValue()
    {
        return this.num;
    }

    public int getIndex()
    {
        return this.index;
    }
}






public class Controller 
{

    private Threads[] threadsArray;
    private int iterations;
    private boolean finished = false;

    private static int numOfThreads;

    public Controller(int n, int m) 
    {
        threadsArray = new Threads[n];

        for(int i=0; i < threadsArray.length; i++)
            threadsArray[i] = new Threads(this, i);

        iterations = m;

        numOfThreads = n;

        printResults();

        for(int i=0; i < threadsArray.length; i++)
            threadsArray[i].start();
    }

    public synchronized void threadWait()
    {
        while(!finished)
        {
            try{ wait(); }
            catch(InterruptedException e) {}
        }
            numOfThreads++;

            waitForAll();

            if(numOfThreads == threadsArray.length)
            {
                finished = false;
                notifyAll();
            }   
    }

    public int checkValue(Threads t, int ind) //returns the thread's value to be updated. 1,-1 or 0.


    public int getIterations()
    {
        return this.iterations;
    }

    public synchronized void finished()
    {
        numOfThreads--;
        notifyAll();

        if(numOfThreads == 0)
            finished = true;
    }

    public void iteration()
    {
        for(int i=0; i < threadsArray.length; i++)
            threadsArray[i].start();
    }

    public synchronized void updated()
    {
        numOfThreads--;

        if(numOfThreads == 0) 
        {
            printResults();
            finished = true;
            notifyAll(); 
        }
    }

    public synchronized void waitForAll()
    {
        while(numOfThreads != threadsArray.length)
        {
            try{ wait(); }
            catch(InterruptedException e) {}
        }
    }

    public void printResults() // prints the result on each iteration.
}
```

Comment: Just for the record: consider a different name then `Threads` . That is super easy to misread for "Thread".

Comment: @GhostCat What do you mean? with the ```this```

Comment: I had a look at the "source" of your question. You have triple backticks all over the place. That gives you the `here comes code` formatting. I wanted to improve your question a bit, but after clicking on "edit" and looking at this plethora of backticks, I immediately hit cancel and decided to not to.

Comment: I tried that already. Same result

Comment: Then step back. For each of your methods, think up *exactly* what you expect to happen. Ask yourself how you can verify that *exactly* the expected happen. Yes, debugging is hard. But there are no detours. Worst case, you might want to learn how to create and read a thread dump to understand "where" your threads are, and what they are waiting for.